# Getting an error iterating an array in ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I have retrieved all users stored in my database using `user.find({})` and stored in a variable: `me`. Then I wrote a callback function which is iterating `me` (array of users) and printing all the statuses using:

```
me.forEach(function(status) {
    console.log(status.status);
});
```

But when I sent the same to an `ejs` file and iterate, I am getting an error saying `me.forEach is not a function`.

Comment: What is `me`? Please share that too

Comment: please share the relevant part  from your ejs file and the full query to your DB